# Laravel 5.3 Hiding Links from Certain User Types

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

I'm building an app with 3 different users (developer, client and patron). I'm trying to hide links from different users. I know you can do this like this:

```
@if (Auth::guest())
<li><a href="{{ url('developer/login') }}">Developer Login</a></li>
<li><a href="{{ url('client/login') }}">Client Login</a></li>
<li><a href="{{ url('patron/login') }}">Patron Login</a></li>
@endif
```

But how would I hide links from developers, if you're logged in as a patron? I'm using Hesto's Multi-Auth: https://github.com/Hesto/multi-auth

Answer (score 0):

Here is an idea to work with different users type you should add is_admin set it by default 0 and for these three users add 1,2,3 respectively then use condition as

```
@if(Auth::user()->is_admin==1)
<li><a href="{{ url('developer/login') }}">Developer Login</a></li>
@endif
```

For 2nd User `is_admin==2` same as above and so on 
I am using same as in my project hope it will helpful for you

Comment: How would I do this if I added an enum value to the database? A dropdown with just user_1 and user_2 in it?

Comment: it cannot be in this way you should remove enum then it can work ... you need to create an extra field as is_admin and set it by default 0 and according to their roles you can manually change it to 1,2 and 3